# Translating proc mixed to lmer - SAS to R

Tags: r, mixed-models, lmer

I have the following SAS code that I would like to write in R. I know the class statement is redundant in R (not necessary).

```
proc mixed data=in_data;
class G F K kal;
model conc=;
random G F K(F) kal(G*F*K);
ods output covparms=out.cov_out;
run;
```

I tried the below code, with no luck.

fit <- lmer( conc ~ (1 | G) + (1 | F) + (1 | K/F) + (1  | kal/G:F:K) , sample_1)

with the following output. I was hoping not to get a value for kal or K.

```
summary(fit)

Random effects:
 Groups    Name        Variance  Std.Dev.
 G:F:K:kal (Intercept) 1.421e-04 0.011921
 F:K       (Intercept) 1.326e-05 0.003641
 F         (Intercept) 6.548e-05 0.008092
 kal       (Intercept) 9.852e-06 0.003139
 K         (Intercept) 1.272e-05 0.003567
 G         (Intercept) 2.165e-03 0.046527
 Residual              4.647e-04 0.021557
```

Comment: I am getting close to the output that I need.

Comment: Try `conc ~ (1 | G) + (1 | F/K) + (kal| G:F:K)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Your formula translates to:

`conc ~` value is modelled using `G + F` fixed effects `(K|F)` random slope of `K` varying on `G` and `(Z|G/F/K)` random slope of `Z` varying on `K` nested in `F` nested in `G`. Also, while you use `\` rather then `:`, this translates to: `(Z|G) + (Z|G:F) + (Z|G:F:K)`. You do not use `0 +` or `- 1` in your definition, so intercept is included.

So your model translates to: `conc ~ 1 + G + F + (1 + K|F) + (1 + Z|G) + (1 + Z|G:F) + (1 + Z|G:F:K)`. Is this what you wanted?

What may be problematic is that in your definition `K` is both the random slope and grouping variable for random effects - is it for purpose?

Check an article by [Bates et al. (in press)](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.5823.pdf) on `lme4` and formulas in this package.

Comment: maybe original model was supposed to be `random G F K(F) K(G*F*Z);` ??

Comment: The code I used now is: `fit <- lmer( conc ~ (1 | G) + (1 | F) + (1 | K/F) + (1  | kal/G:F:K) , sample_1)`